# Paypal Integration

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation

i would like to integrate Paypal payments to my Wordpress website, in order to send a digital product. I only want a simple redirection to the paypal payments form, to either pay through paypal or with a credit card (i have a payments standard account there).

The problem is the notifications system. I would like my client to be able to download my digital product right after the payment has occurred.

Is there a plugin that handles this situation and makes sure that payment and delivery happen normally (using the paypal notifications system) ?

I was taking a look at Paypal Framework and i happen to be a programmer. If i take a closer look at that, would it allow me to do what i want ?

Answer (score 0):

The best plugin that i know of that's free but has a few premium addons is WP-Ecommerce, it's very simple to use and features quite a few different payment gateways apart from PayPal.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-e-commerce/

Comment: i have tried it but it messes with my website's css and i had to drop that. Moreover, it is too much for what i want to do, it's mostly directed towards shopping carts and so on. It's generally not an option in my case.

Comment: In that case you could try a class i just happened to find today at http://www.binpress.com/app/php-paypal-pro-adaptive-api-class/612, it's simply a copy, paste and fill in the blanks API that has a sandbox mode for development testing.

Answer (score 0):

The most seamless e-commerce plugin experience I've had thus far is with [JigoShop](http://jigoshop.com/). A while back WooThemes forked their code and created [WooCommerce](http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/). Both are similar, viable options, but I prefer [JigoShop](http://jigoshop.com/) because they were the originators of the product.

Basically, everything runs off shortcodes without having to import templates into your theme (though you can) and customize styles to make it work with your theme. It just works out-of-the-box.